# Java synchronized method with expensive parameters

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a synchronized method that *appears* to be 'using' the synchronization for significantly longer than it should. It looks something like;

```
public static synchronized void myMethod(MyParameter p) {
    //body (not expensive)
}
```

The call looks like;

```
myMethod(generateParameter());
```

Where `generateParameter()` is known to be a very expensive (takes a long time) call. My thinking is that the mutex on the `myMethod` class is blocked during the execution of `generateParameter()` is this what happens? I'm finding it a different problem to debug but this is what appears to be going on.

Comment: Is `generateParameter` also synchronized at the method level?

Comment: code for `generateParameter` is required to give proper answer.

Comment: `generateParameter()` is not synchronized and exists as a static method in an otherwise unrelated class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can't be it; the `generateParameter()` call is executed first, and its results are then given as an argument to the `myMethod` call, which *then* grabs the mutex.

Is it taking long, or is it indefinitely blocked? (a deadlock)

Comment: I was 99% sure that was how method parameters work, but it just seemed to fit as an explanation. Thanks, I will have to profile it properly.

Comment: So, when you say the synchronization takes longer than it should, you mean that on top of the time you expect for `getParameter()` it takes even longer? Maybe you should try to understand what that extra time goes to. I'd be curious as to what it ended up being, so you might want to update us all later :)

Comment: All the other threads are blocking waiting on this lock for several seconds, and the body of `myMethod()` is known to be cheap (~<10ms). I'm sure there is a sensible explanation, I just had a moment where I wondered about when the lock is acquired.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not what happens.

Method `generateParameter` is executed before call to `myMethod`.

**In Java, all method arguments are always evaluated before method call.**

The [specification of method call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) explains it in detail (thanks to Victor Sorokin).

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is located. Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code.

Your code is the same as the one below, except of new variable:

```
MyParameter p = generateParameter();
myMethod(p);
```

Comment: In Java, all method arguments are always evaluated before method call: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4

Answer (score 2):

The thread executing `myMethod` enters the object's monitor at the beginning of the method and holds it until it exits. Any operations done inside the method are `synchronized`, but all call parameters are evaluated before the call is made, so `generateParameter` is not executing inside `myMethod`'s lock window.

If `generateParameter` has any synchronization on it, though, it could be contending for the same lock, since without an explicit synchronization object the JVM synchronizes on the object whose method is being called.

I strongly suggest profiling the code to determine where it's really getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `static synchronized void myMethod(p)` its better to use `ReadWriteLock` for your resources:

```
MyParameter p = generateParameter();

myMethod(p){

  ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();


  readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

    // multiple readers can enter this section
    // if not locked for writing, and not writers waiting
    // to lock for writing.

  readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();


  readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

    // only one writer can enter this section,
    // and only if no threads are currently reading.

  readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I do tend to use synchronized liberally and often overlook other concurrency tools.

Answer (score 0):

"the mutex on the myMethod class is blocked during the execution of generateParameter()"

As far as I know the lock is not acquired until the execution of the `generateParameter` function ends.